# Laravel Authentication with condition

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel 5.1 and Laravel's default authentication system.

In database (MySQL) I add a new column named 'role'. The value will be 1 for admin and 2 for members.

Now I want to give login permission only for admin, means where the value is 1. How can I do that?

Comment: So just to clarify, what do you want admins to be able to do? Giving login permission sounds like you only want admins to be able to log in to your site

Comment: Yes I want only admin can login.

Comment: Ok, but what's the point in allowing a member to sign up if they cannot log in? Or are you looking to just restrict part of your site to admins only?

Comment: Members are not always allowed to log in.

Comment: But if you only allow admins to log in then members can never log in. I want to help but I'm quite unclear on what you actually want as an end result. You are building an application that has members and admins, but where admins are the only ones that can log in based on what you've asked for. Which doesn't really make sense because what is the point in having members in the first place as they can never log in.

Comment: member will be able to login for a certain period. after few days member will not be able to login only admin can login. and there will be some blocked member too who will never allowed to login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I solved it. I just add these code in `postLogin()` method of `AthenticatesUsers.php` method.

```
    // If role is equal to 1, user allowed to login
    // You can change $admin value anytime according to database Design
    // Example: In role column the value for admin is 2 or A. You just need to change the value of $admin.
    $userData = User::select('role')->where('email',$request['email'])->first();
    $admin = 1;
    $role = $userData->role;
    if($role == $admin){
        $request['role'] = $role;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel that there are better ways to achieve what you're after, such as [middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware), however given what you're after this would be one way to do it.

Upon logging in a user us sent to 'home', unless you specify otherwise in the `AuthController`.

Inside your `routes.php`, if you just set up a `GET` route to point to a `HomeController` (or whatever you name it) then you could use a function to run the tests you're after.

**routes.php**

`Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');`

**HomeController**

```
public function index()
    {
        //If they are yet to log in then return your normal homepage
        if (Auth::guest())
        {
            return View::make('home');
        }
        else
        {
           //Run your tests here to check their role and direct appropriately
           //Given you have added the role column to the users table, you can access it like so:
           //Auth::user()->role
        }
    }
```